# intelliJ and Bitbucket, where to start a project

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I want to create a new project in IntelliJ and and create a git repository for it. Should I create a project in intelliJ first and then clone repository (I dont know how to do it this right now) Or should I create a repository in Git (bit Bucket), Clone it it and then import in IntelliJ
Does it matter how I do it ?

Comment: Both should work, use whatever is more convenient for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter how I do it

Not really, but I prefer the second approach: it validates the BitBucket/git clone part.

*Then*, once that first step is working, you can add IntelliJ to the process, and import the project. IntelliJ will detect the Git repository and propose Team sharing features automatically.